# OpenCV 3.2.0 iOS Type Conversion: int to __CLPK_integer *

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, casting

I am trying to implement OpenCV 3.2.0 as a static library inside of an iOS app. I have created an `opencv.xcodeproj` project inside my workspace to build the static libraries, which I then link to my main app project, like so:

[image: workspace structure]

[image: static library linking]

The file `hal_internal.cpp` in `opencv_core` will not compile due to a type conversion error. This is a sample of the problem code, shortened:

```
lapack_LU(fptype* a, size_t a_step, int m, fptype* b, size_t b_step, int n, int* info)
{
    int lda = (int)(a_step / sizeof(fptype)), sign = 0;
    int* piv = new int[m];

    transpose_square_inplace(a, lda, m);

    if(b)
    {
        if(n == 1 && b_step == sizeof(fptype))
        {
            if(typeid(fptype) == typeid(float))
                sgesv_(&m, &n, (float*)a, &lda, piv, (float*)b, &m, info);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler error is `No matching function for call to sgesv_` because the `m` parameter, which is an `int` is not of type `__CLPK_integer`.

This is the function signature:

```
int sgesv_(__CLPK_integer *__n, __CLPK_integer *__nrhs, __CLPK_real *__a,
        __CLPK_integer *__lda, __CLPK_integer *__ipiv, __CLPK_real *__b,
        __CLPK_integer *__ldb,
        __CLPK_integer *__info) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_2,
        __IPHONE_4_0);
```

`__CLPK_integer` is defined in `clapack.h` in the Accelerate framework as:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) /* In LP64 match sizes with the 32 bit ABI */
    typedef int         __CLPK_integer;
    ...
#else
    typedef long int    __CLPK_integer;
    ...
#endif
```

If I try to create a buffer and use it instead:

```
__CLPK_integer newM = m;

...

sgesv_(&newM, &n, (float*)a, &lda, piv, (float*)b, &m, info);
```

I get the same compiler error.

If I try

```
__CLPK_integer* newM = (int*)m;

...

sgesv_(newM, &n, (float*)a, &lda, piv, (float*)b, &m, info);
```

The compiler can find the function `sgesv_` but issues an error at the `newM` declaration:

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type '__CLPK_integer *' (aka 'long *') with an rvalue of type 'int *'
```

Also, why does the compiler think `__CLPK_integer` is now `aka 'long *'`?

If I instead try to cast `__CLPK_integer* newM = (long*)m;` I get the same error but then the compiler thinks __CLPK_integer is `aka 'int *'`.

I am building against `Generic iOS Device` and `Build Active Architecture Only` set to Yes.

How to I convert the int `m` to the expected type `__CLPK_integer *`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&m is getting passed in for 2 of the parameters, the first and the seventh.

Seems like something like this should work:

```
sgesv_((__CLPK_integer*)&m, &n, (float*)a, &lda, piv, (float*)b,(__CLPK_integer*)&m, info);
```

You might also need to cast parameters 2, 4, 5 and 8.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Never underestimate the power of fresh eyes.

I did indeed end up having to cast all the parameters. That call now looks like this: 
 sgesv_(
        (__CLPK_integer*)&m,
        (__CLPK_integer*)&n,
        (float*)a,
        (__CLPK_integer*)&lda,
        piv,
        (float*)b,
        (__CLPK_integer*)&m,
        (__CLPK_integer*)&info
     );